# d3 transform-origin with two needles in a clock

Tags: javascript, d3.js, web-audio-api

This is my first project using D3, and I'm using WebAudioAPI to get microphone input to represent where the needles point. I got them to move, however my minute needle is going beserk and not rotating on a specific point or staying still.

```
var width = 960,
height = 500,
τ = 2 * Math.PI; 

var arc = d3.svg.arc()
 .innerRadius(180) 
 .outerRadius(240)
 .startAngle(0);


var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
 .attr("width", width)
 .attr("height", height)
 .append("g")
 .attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + height / 2 + ")");



var background = svg.append("path")
 .datum({endAngle: 100})
 .style("fill", "#ddd")
 .attr("d", arc);


var foreground = svg.append("path")
 .datum({endAngle: .1 * τ})
 .style("fill", "orange")
 .attr("d", arc);

var gaugeGroup = svg.append("g")
 .datum({endAngle: .1 * τ})
 .attr("class", "hour hands")
.attr("transform", "translate( 0 , 0 )");

var hour = gaugeGroup.append("path")
 .attr("class", "tri")
 .attr("d", "M" + (600/2 + 12) + " " + (240 + 10) + " L" + 600/2 + " 0 L" + (600/2 - 3) + " " + (240 + 10) + " C" + (600/2 - 3) + " " + (240 + 20) + " " + (600/2 + 3) + " " + (240 + 20) + " " + (600/2 + 12) + " " + (240 + 10) + " Z")
// .attr("transform", "rotate(-60, " + -70 + "," + (389) + ")");
.attr("transform", "translate(-300,-250) rotate(0,0,0)");

var minute = gaugeGroup.append("path")
 .attr("class", "tri")
 .attr("d", "M" + (300/2 + 3) + " " + (170 + 10) + " L" + 300/2 + " 0 L" + (300/2 - 3) + " " + (170 + 10) + " C" + (300/2 - 3) + " " + (170 + 20) + " " + (300/2 + 3) + " " + (170 + 20) + " " + (300/2 + 3) + " " + (170 + 10) + " Z")

.attr("transform", "translate(-150,-188) rotate(0,0,0)");
```

// Add the background arc, from 0 to 100% (τ).

```
function setValues(note, detune){

 foreground.transition()
  .duration(190)
  .call(arcTween, note / 10);
 gaugeGroup
 .transition()
 .duration(200)
 .attr("transform", "rotate("+note *τ +",0,0)");
 minute
 .transition()
 .duration(150)
 .attr("transform","rotate("+detune * τ +",200,6)");
}
```

Comment: Ransom Namba, this sounds like a problem that I had, and solved, but I don't know anything about WebAudioAPI.  I would suggest trying to reproduce the problem without WebAudioAPI.  Use fake data if necessary, or collect some audio data and put it into a file.  If the problem persists, then the question is not about WebAudioAPI, and d3 users like me who don't know it can help.  With fake data, you can put the whole thing in a fiddle so we can see how it's supposed to work.  Or if the problem goes away, then it's probably a purely WebAudio problem, but you will have a clearer sense of it.

Comment: Sorry, the problem has nothing to do with WebAudioAPI, strictly a D3 problem, with the minute hand. Guess it was irrelevant to add that I was using it, sorry!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nearly impossible to debug this without access to the working code (or a fiddle). But from just glancing at it, a couple of things stand out:

- You're applying rotation to the entire `gaugeGroup`, which contains both the hours and minutes hands, and then you apply local rotation to the `minute` group. This might be appropriate but only if `detune` is a relative value in a range of 0 +/- *n* (i.e. when `detune == 0` the minutes and hours hands would be expected to overlap). If `detune` is expressed in absolute terms, it would mean that your code is transforming the minute hand twice — once through `gaugeGroup` and again through `minute`.
- It would be easier for you to understand what's happening and debug it if you set things up such that you can simply rotate `minute` around its origin 0,0 instead of having to specify a different rotation origin in `rotate("+detune * τ +",200,6)`. For that, you would need to modify the minute path's `"d"` attribute (as in `minute.attr("d", ...)`) such that its pivot point is at 0,0. Before you do that, for the purpose of debugging, you can simplify the minutes path to be just a line from the origin out — somthing like `M0 0 L150 0` (see how it starts at 0,0) — get the rotation working properly without offsetting the rotation origin and then bring back the more complex path.